# Restore My Raspberry Pi from copied files

Tags: sd-card, restore

I needed my Raspberry Pi SD card for something urgently one day so I just quickly copied the files from the SD card directly into a folder on my Windows desktop.

I know I should've made an image file but did not have the time.

Is there a way to restore my Raspberry Pi to boot off those copied files?

Thanks

Comment: This is like asking :  I've saved some parts of my house before purposefully destroying it. Can i rebuild it again ? Answer : Depends on the saved parts.

Comment: Probably not as I doubt you've copied anything but the fat32 partition, which holds essentially nothing but operating system settings

Comment: I would suggest you create a new SD card with the OS you previous SD card used, then use FTP or SSH to transfer the files you need back to the SD card. I never try but this should works depends on what you would needed and what you've copied. No guaranteed.

Comment: ok, obviously I have made a serious mistake by not making an image of the SD card as I have confirmed all I have now is a copy of the fat32 partition. I am still learning how to develop with the Raspberry Pi and this is definitely a good lesson. Thank you for your help